# Open PDF reusing code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf

How to open pdf in my asp.net mvc website? But reusing code and which I have not. I do not want to do this for each pdf, so I want to reuse code.

My Index View:

```
<p>@Html.ActionLink("Historia.pdf", "ObtenerPdf", "Home")</p>
```

My Controller Method:

```
public FileStreamResult ObtenerPdf()
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("c:\\Historia.pdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    return File(fs, "application/pdf");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, I don't have VS in front of me to check.

---

In summary, you need to add a parameter to your DownloadPdf action and pass it in with the action link.

Here's some code to list all the PDFs (Q used C:\ so this does as well, see notes), show them to the user and download.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\", "*.pdf")
                    .Select(x => System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x))
                    .ToList();
    return View(files);
}

public FileStreamResult ObtenerPdf(string file)
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("c:\\" + file + ".pdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    return File(fs, "application/pdf");
}
```

View:

```
@model IList<string>

@foreach (var file in Model)
{
    <p>@Html.ActionLink(file, "ObtenerPdf", "Home", new { file }, null)</p>
}
```

Couple of notes:

`Directory.GetFiles` includes the path - there are other methods to get a list of files without the path included.

`ActionLink` overload is: text, action, controller, routeValues, attributes - without the null it will pick the wrong overload.

In `new { file }` if you don't specify a name, it will use the variable name, you could be specific to match the parameter name on the action which would be more robust, ie:  `new { file = file }` but some optimisers will highlight this.

You *probably* don't want to list all your PDFs on C:\ on the server... you can use `Server.MapPath` to locate a folder within your application (then it doesn't matter if your site moves)

There's very likely an overload for return File to specify the path, so you don't need to open it first and will dispose it for you correctly etc, I've used the same code as supplied in the question.